# Pattern for syncronously loading a react Provider component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client, react-hooks, react-context

My :brain: is exploding.

In the root of my application I want to set a UserProvider (simplified version below).

I want all consumers of it to have confidence that the Provider has the user.

With the following implementation  I need to do a null check on every use:

```
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext)
  const userId = userContext!.id   // I do not want that bang(!)
```

My current implementation:

```
interface IUserContext {
  id: string
  email: string
}

const UserContext = React.createContext<IUserContext|null>(null);

const UserProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(initalContext);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    client
      .query<CurrentUserQuery>({
        query: currentUserQuery
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.error) {
          logger(res.error);
        }
        if (res.data.me) {
          setUser(res.data.me);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      });
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

I know that I can do something like:

```
const emptyUser = {
  id: '',
  email: ''
}

const UserContext = React.createContext(emptyUser);
```

But that smells really bad to me.

Has anyone come up with a clean solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess if the Provider will only ever be mounted if your user has been loaded then you could just assert the user value like `<UserContext.Provider value={user as IUserContext}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;`.

Comment: ooooo thats smart

Comment: hrrmmm that still didn't work for me -- still get "Object is possibly undefined" as a compilation error

Comment: Have you looked into [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)?

Answer (score 1):

You declared your context to accept either a `IUserContext` or `null`, which is why you need the bang!.

A solution for unwrapping a `User` from the context would be to throw an exception if the user is `null` (which should not happen anyway ?). Then Typescript would infer that your user is in fact not null but an actual `User`

```
const userContext = createContext<User | null>(null)

const useUser = (): User => {
  const user = useContext(userContext)

  if (user === null) {
    throw new Error('You forgot the provider')
  }

  return user // This is a User
}
```

Comment: Cool -- I like this approach.  I'll give it a shot.  i think that final `return user` can be improved as `return user as User`